# Can I use a dot in a config file of Fluentd using DSL?

Tags: ruby, dsl, fluentd

guys.
I'm been using Fluentd on my Rails app, and I want to write the config file  of Fluentd using DSL. However, my config file doesn't work well. This may be caused by a dot.

Here is my config file.

```
# config/fluent/fluent.rb

source {
  type :forward
}

['access','debug','error'].each do|tag|
  if tag == 'access'
    filter("#{tag}.app.**") {
      type :record_transformer
      enable_ruby
      record {
        hoge '${hoge ? hoge : "-"}'
        fuga.piyo '${fuga ? fuga : "-"}'
      }
    }
  end

.......
```

And, when I execute a below command,

```
$bundle exec fluentd -c config/fluent/fluent.rb -vv
```

"fuga" and "piyo" fields are not correct.

```
<source>
  type forward
</source>
<filter access.app.**>
  type record_transformer
  enable_ruby 
  <record>
    hoge ${hoge ? hoge : "-"}
    fuga 
    piyo ${fuga ? fuga : "-"}
  </record>
</filter>
```

Can you understand why?Please, help me...

Thanks.

Comment: How would correct `fuga` and `piyo` entries look like?

Comment: Thanks. I want for them to look like...

`fuga.piyo ${fuga ? fuga : "-"}`

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I'm a fluentd committer and developer of config dsl.

It seems a kind of bug, and cannot find any simple workaround except for `self.send "fuga.piyo".to_sym, '${fuga ? fuga : "-"}'`.
I hope an issue for this on github.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll post a issue for this problem on Github.

Comment: I posted this issue. [https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/612](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/612)